# bundle css into one file

Tags: javascript, css, bundle

I would like to bundle multiple css files into 1 file. I have considered webpack but it from what documentation I have seen webpack's style requires you to bundle all your files html+css+js together which I can not due to my applications architecture.

Is there some way to bundle js and css without bundle the html as well? or rather bundling them independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gulp`

Install dependencies:

```
npm install --global gulp-cli
npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-concat gulp-cssnano gulp-uglify
```

Create gulpfile.js like this:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('bundle-css', () => {
    return gulp.src('css/*.css')
        .pipe(concat('bundle.css'))
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('bundle-js', () => {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('bundle-css', 'bundle-js'));
```

To bundle both run:

```
gulp
```

To bundle by task run:

```
gulp bundle-css
gulp bundle-js
```